# How to include font-awesome (that was instolled via nuget) in my layout in a .Net Core project?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget, font-awesome

I have a simple `.Net Core` project with the following `.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="bootstrap" Version="4.3.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Font.Awesome" Version="5.9.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.2.4" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

As you can see, it contains `Bootstrap`. And it works nice with `Bootstrap`. I can see it in my `wwwroot` folder after restoring project:

[image]

But what about `Font-Awesome`? I don't see the sources of the library after restoring the project. So, I have a question: how I can include `Font-Awesome` to my `_Layout.cshtml` file?

#### P.S

I've found `Font-Awesome` here:

[image]

But I don't understand how I can use it for this place.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012147/razor-core-installing-jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-missing-js-files). It doesn't matter that the package being used is different, if you read my answer, you'll see it's a generic issue for front end/javascript libraries in ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the package, you can find the package files in

`C:/Users/Your Current User/.nuget/packages/font.awesome`.

Inside the "content" dir, there are all the files and they can be manaully imported into the project `wwwroot` folder to be used like other static files.