# How to find and use downloaded packages from nuget in vs2017 software (and in an asp.net core project)?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

In Visual Studio 2017, I use the following command to install a package like .jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation -Version 3.2.11
```

And the operation is done successfully.
Now I'm looking for files on wwwroot but can not find anything? what is the problem?

Comment: For client side packages use LibMan or Bower. Please check this link for LibMan-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Razor Core installing jquery.unobtrusive.ajax missing js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012147/razor-core-installing-jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-missing-js-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LibMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.2) :

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project folder in which the files should be added. Choose `Add` > `Client-Side Library`.
2. Type `jquery-validation-unobtrusive@3.2.11` in `Library` input area .
3. Click `Install` , the library will install to target location . The default is `wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/`